# lookup forms in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qt4

Bit of an open question but....

Is it possible to design a form in qt designer that will be used as a form against a qgis layer but interacts with a different table in postgres/postgis as a lookup table.

For example, I have a postgis layer that i'm editing in qgis to capture the locations of shops. Some of the fields to capture are address, postcode and parish. Could I do a lookup to another postgres/postgis table to enable these fields to auto-populated my shops form field?

Si

Comment: Do you mean just a attribute table with values that you want to show in a dropdown?

Comment: Yep, thats what im after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  The best way to do this is to use the Value Relation widget type.

1. Load your postgis table as a attribute only layer
2. Select Value Relation on vector layer and set the layer, key, and value

[image]

`Key` is what is shown to the user and `Value` is what is stored in the field when selected.

In the past I have also just had a single attribute layer with three columns `control`, `key`, `value`.  Then I filter for each control using the expression `control = 'CommonName'`. This allows you to have a single table for all dropdowns on the form and just update it all in one place.

Comment: Cheers Nathan, not at my desk the moment but will give it a whirl as soon as I can. Looks like what I'm after :-)

Comment: starting to have a play and I was wondering if it is possible to have a 'search' type lookup and not a dropdown list. My address database has 85k records in it!

Comment: For that I think you might need something a bit more custom.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Nathan, do you still plan to update the answer. I also need exactly this functionality. Thnaks